# Facebook Graph API, Action ID and which object

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a FB App and I can successfully post actions and objects with the Open Graph API to the timeline, ticker, and chronicle.

My question is, is there a way to get the action id returned written into the mysql database or from the action id get the actual object title returned and written this to the database?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with AJAX.

For example:

```
 function postNewAction()
 {
      passString = '&object=http://site.com/APP_NAMESPACE/object.php';

      FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION' + passString,'post',
         function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert(response.error.message);
              } 
              else {
                  storeInTable(response.id);
              } 
          }
      );    
 }

 function storeInTable(id){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //Success!     
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","storeInTable.php?id=" + id,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
 }
```

And then you would store the id to your table in storeInTable.php of course.

This may not be the best way - maybe it is, I don't know - but will do what youre requesting.